# Does an avocado ripen faster in a paper bag?

Tags: nutrition, physics

I've always heard that an avocado could ripen faster if put in a paper bag.

These claims can be found in many places on the internet :

- [The best way to ripen avocados](http://www.whfoods.com/genpage.php?tname=foodtip&dbid=16)
- [How to ripen an avocado](http://www.wikihow.com/Ripen-an-Avocado)

Here is a quote from the first link :

> Place unripe avocados in a brown paper bag to ripen. This traps the ethylene gas they produce and helps them to ripen. A firm avocado placed in a paper bag will ripen at room temperature in about three to six days. As the fruit ripens, the skin color will darken.

Is that true?

Comment: Related (and there's several others on the same site): http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/109/why-does-a-brown-paper-bag-speed-ripening  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/23691/how-can-i-let-fruit-ripen-faster

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Ripen-an-Avocado suggests using other fruits which emit ethylene.

Comment: I am looking for more scientific sources than the comments and first answer. Near miss: [plastic bags *delay* ripening](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304423881900169).